# EAP (Re)authentification every 8:20 hours

Tags: wireless-networking, hostapd, radius

I have a network that uses Freeradius and hostapd to authentificate. Every ~ 8:20 hours (30000 sec or 500 min) a connected station disconnects (gets disconnected?) and a new (Re?)authentification occures. I sat  eap_reauth_period=10000000 in hostapd. Does anyone know about timeouts in this range that could be involved? I'm thinking about Radius Session-Timeout (how can I verify it?) and maybe PMK timouts (is there something like this?) etc...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have done this already, but after you make a change to hostapd, you must restart the FreeRadius service.  Once the service is restarted, you must reboot your Access Point (Providing you are wireless) and you must de-authenticate your client and re-authenticate your client.

Comment: I dont restart hostapd.

Comment: You MUST restart hostapd for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I know. I meant that I have the parameter inside the default configuration file that hostapd uses when starting up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Pairwise-Master-Key has a Lifetime that is 
calculated by formula 
dot11RSNAConfigPMKLifetime * dot11RSNAConfigPMKReauthThreshold / 100.
The default values are
dot11RSNAConfigPMKLifetime=43200
dot11RSNAConfigPMKReauthThreshold=70 which results in
30240 seconds. Which is around 8 hours.